Iteration v-for over arrays defined on i18n(v9) with Vue3
I am starting to use the Vue i18n plugin and everything was going smoothly until I had to iterate over an array to render Vue components with a v-for directive.
The array with the objects (one per component) containing the strings to be passed as props to said components has this structure:
{
  "abouts": [
    {
      "title": "Title1",
      "description": "Description1"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title2",
      "description": "Description2"
    },
    ...
  ],
}

So at the end, what I want to do is to have a component  being rendered via a v-for directive as many times as there are objects within the array in 'abouts', passing the localized strings as props to the component. Something like this:
<AboutBox v-for="about in abouts" :title="about.title" :description="about.description" />
I was reading the documentation and so far I cannot make heads nor tails of it. I know I have to use  tm and rt as documented here: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#tm-key and in the migration guide fo v9 https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/migration/breaking#translation-api-return-value.
I tried using that for my template and I wrote this:
<AboutBox 
   v-for="(about, index) in abouts" 
   :key="index" 
   :title="$rt(about.title)" 
   :description="$rt(about.description)" 
/>


While my script look like this:
import type { About } from '@/plugins/i18n'
import AboutBox from './AboutBox.vue'
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
// Accessing i18n
const { tm } = useI18n()
const abouts = computed(() => tm('abouts') as About[])

Where the About type is:
interface About {
  title: string
  description: string
}

And I used a computed property because otherwise the data is not reactive.
With this code everything works as expected but I am not really sure that I am doing it the way it is supposed to be done (I don't really understand that documentation fully). If someone with more experience, or another solution, can provide their insight, I thank you.

It remains unclear if the use of tm/rt is justified. What's the intention behind "abouts"? Obscure strings like Title1 don't give a clue of what it might be. If you need data collection, you can create it outside locale messages and use message keys where needed, like let abouts = [{ title: 'FOO_TITLE', ..., then it would be t(about.title) in a template

Hello Ashen One ;) The 'abouts' is a static set of strings. One can find it in several json files, one per language translated. I created the const as a computed property as a way to give it type checking, because if I used $tm('abouts') directly in the v-for, I had a type error because about was of type 'never'.

I also found that I could use ($tm('abouts') as About[]) within the v-for loop instead of the const abouts. But I had syntax highlighting issues in my editor (vs code).

You can naturally have problems using TS in a template. Vue SFC format is non-standard and you depend on how the tools support it. It's even more important how vue-tsc supports it rather than an editor. If you want to make it more compatible, use computed() with tm() as you did. In my practice keeping data that's used in app logic apart from the translations the way I suggested was cleaner.

Thank you @EstusFlask for the help and the suggestion!
